# How to install OpenNI 2.1 on Mac?

Tags: kinect, openni

I can not find installation instructions for this version of OpenNI. I have a Kinect for Windows and Mac OSX 10.8.

It is listed as the downloadable on [OpenNI.org](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/), but there are no installation instructions on that site (that I can find) and the [OpenNI2 Github page](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2) does not have instructions for Mac.

So, I tried downloading the repository and running:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

As is typical to do with the previous version. I get no response, just the prompt back. When I run

```
./Tools/NiViewer
```

I get

```
openDevice failed:
DeviceOpen using default: no devices found

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Through the libfreenect mailing list, I found these two discussions about Kinect for Windows support [{1}](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/) and [{2}](http://answers.ros.org/answers/35351/revisions/)

Comment: I bought a Kinect for Xbox and OpenNI works fine with that.

Comment: are u using Kinect v2 ? Did u ever figure this out ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a library called libfreenect, as well as libusb. The easiest way to do it on your mac is too add the brew package manager, and from your command line dial up:#brew install libfreenect

The link below will guide you (it worked for me) http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#OS_X

Comment: I had already installed libfreenect, and followed the instructions on that page.

Comment: libfreenect does work, but it doesn't provide the higher level functions of skeletal tracking. Basically, it is a driver that is reverse engineered and accesses raw functionality of the Kinect